# Insert or update mapped model data into database

Tags: c#, asp.net, dapper

I got my code works fine, but I am not really sure whether the approach that I took is a best practice or not. So, I decided to ask in this forum instead.

So here is my situation:

I got my model which looks like this:

```
public class Member
{
    [Range(1, int.MaxValue)]
    public int? MemberID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public List<MemberExperience> MemberExperiences { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string MemberAddress { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public MemberInformation MemberInformation { get; set; }
}

public class MemberExperience
{
    [Required]
    [Range(1, int.MaxValue)]
    public int FromYear { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Range(1, int.MaxValue)]
    public int ToYear { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string CompanyAddress { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ProgrammingLanguage { get; set; }
}

public class MemberInformation
{
    [Required]
    public string FullName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string TelephoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```

And from the client side, what I pass to the server is like this:

```
{
   "MemberExperiences": [
    {
        "FromYear": 2005,
        "ToYear": 2008,
        "CompanyAddress": "string",
        "ProgrammingLanguage": "Javascript"
    },
    {
        "FromYear": 2009,
        "ToYear": 2012,
        "CompanyAddress": "string",
        "ProgrammingLanguage": "C++"
    },
    {
        "FromYear": 2013,
        "ToYear": 2017,
        "CompanyAddress": "string",
        "ProgrammingLanguage": "C#"
    }
  ],
  "MemberAddress": "string",
  "MemberInformation": {
      "FullName": "string",
      "BirthDate": "1992-01-01",
      "TelephoneNumber": "string"
  }
}
```

Then my controller looked like this (the data that I want to pass from client side, will converted into `Member` model which have all data in it):

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpActionResult AddMember([FromBody] Member member)
{
      var response = AddMemberToDatabase(member);

      return Ok(response);
}
```

But, since I didn't know on how `Dapper` (I am using `Dapper` for communication to Database) convert the mapped variable (in this case `MemberExperience` and `MemberInformation`) into single object and to be recognized. So, what I did is like this:

1. Take all member data, but before insert it to the database, I will make 1 class that stored the list of data from `MemberExperience` and `MemberInformation`.
2. Join all data into 1 single long string with separated by separator that only Database only allow to access it and knows it.

**SingleMember** class:

```
public class SingleMember
{
    public int? MemberID { get; set; }
    public string FromYears { get; set; }
    public string ToYears { get; set; }
    public string CompanyAddresses { get; set; }
    public string ProgrammingLanguages { get; set; }
    public string MemberAddress { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    public string TelephoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```

**AddMemberToDatabase** function:

```
private int AddMemberToDatabase(Member members)
{
    var separator = "$Format";

    var singleMember = new SingleMember
    {
        FromYears = string.Join(separator, members.MemberExperiences.Select(x => x.FromYear)),
        ToYears = string.Join(separator, members.MemberExperiences.Select(x => x.ToYear)),
        CompanyAddresses = string.Join(separator, members.MemberExperiences.Select(x => x.CompanyAddress)),
        ProgrammingLanguages = string.Join(separator, members.MemberExperiences.Select(x => x.ProgrammingLanguage)),
        MemberAddress = members.MemberAddress;
        FullName = members.MemberInformation.FullName;
        BirthDate = members.MemberInformation.BirthDate;
        TelephoneNumber = members.MemberInformation.TelephoneNumber;
    };

    using (TransactionScope trans = new TransactionScope())
    using (IDbConnection conn = new SqlConnection("MyConnection"))
    {
        conn.Open();

        int rowsAffected = conn.Execute("MyStoredProcedure", singleMember);

        trans.Complete();

        return rowsAffected;
    }
}
```

Then, from the `MyStoredProcedure`, it will split the joined data by the defined format `$Format`, and insert it into table 1 by 1 until the item that is being split no more left from being split.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyStoredProcedure]
(
    @FromYears              NVARCHAR(MAX), // will be 2005$Format2009$Format2013
    @ToYears                NVARCHAR(MAX), // will be 2008$Format2012$Format2017
    @CompanyAddresses       NVARCHAR(MAX), // will be string$Formatstring$Formatstring
    @ProgrammingLanguages   NVARCHAR(MAX), // will be Javascript$FormatC++$FormatC#
    @MemberAddress          NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @FullName               NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @BirthDate              DATETIME,
    @TelephoneNumber        NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE
        @MemberCount            INT,
        @FromYear               INT,
        @ToYear                 INT,
        @CompanyAddress         NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @ProgrammingLanguage    NVARCHAR(MAX)

    DECLARE @FromYearTable      TABLE (
        [ID]            INT         IDENTITY,
        [FromYear]      INT         NOT NULL
    )

    DECLARE @ToYearTable        TABLE (
        [ID]            INT         IDENTITY,
        [ToYear]        INT         NOT NULL
    )

    DECLARE @CompanyAddressTable        TABLE (
        [ID]                INT             IDENTITY,
        [CompanyAddress]    NVARCHAR(MAX)   NOT NULL
    )

    DECLARE @ProgrammingLanguageTable           TABLE (
        [ID]                    INT             IDENTITY,
        [ProgrammingLanguage]   NVARCHAR(MAX)   NOT NULL
    )

    DECLARE @MemberTable            TABLE (
        [ID]                    INT             IDENTITY,
        [FromYear]              INT             NOT NULL,
        [ToYear]                INT             NOT NULL,
        [CompanyAddress]        NVARCHAR(MAX)   NOT NULL,
        [ProgrammingLanguage]   NVARCHAR(MAX)   NOT NULL
    )

    INSERT INTO @FromYearTable
    SELECT [SplittedItem] FROM [StringSplit] (@FromYears, '$Format')

    INSERT INTO @ToYearTable
    SELECT [SplittedItem] FROM [StringSplit] (@ToYears, '$Format')

    INSERT INTO @CompanyAddressTable
    SELECT [SplittedItem] FROM [StringSplit] (@CompanyAddresses, '$Format')

    INSERT INTO @ProgrammingLanguageTable
    SELECT [SplittedItem] FROM [StringSplit] (@ProgrammingLanguages, '$Format')

    INSERT INTO @MemberTable
    SELECT a.[FromYear], b.[ToYear], c.[CompanyAddress], d.[ProgrammingLanguage]
    FROM @FromYearTable a
    INNER JOIN @ToYearTable b ON a.[ID] = b.[ID]
    INNER JOIN @CompanyAddressTable c ON a.[ID] = c.[ID]
    INNER JOIN @ProgrammingLanguageTable d ON a.[ID] = d.[ID]

    /*
        Will be like:
        ID  FromYear    ToYear  CompanyAddress  ProgrammingLanguage
        1   2005        2008    string          Javascript
        2   2009        2012    string          C++
        3   2013        2017    string          C#
    */

    SET @MemberCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @MemberTable)

    WHILE (@MemberCount > 0)
    BEGIN
        SET @FromYear = (SELECT TOP 1 [FromYear] FROM @MemberTable WHERE [ID] = @MemberCount)
        SET @ToYear = (SELECT TOP 1 [ToYear] FROM @MemberTable WHERE [ID] = @MemberCount)
        SET @CompanyAddress = (SELECT TOP 1 [CompanyAddress] FROM @MemberTable WHERE [ID] = @MemberCount)
        SET @ProgrammingLanguage = (SELECT TOP 1 [ProgrammingLanguage] FROM @MemberTable WHERE [ID] = @MemberCount)

        INSERT INTO [MyTable] (@FromYear, @ToYear, @CompanyAddress, @ProgrammingLanguage, @MemberAddress, @FullName, @BirthDate, @TelephoneNumber)

        SET @MemberCount -= 1
    END
END
```

Is there any better way of doing this?

Your answer much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: how is the data mapped in DB? How many tables do you store data into? Can you provide some details about that too?

Comment: Hi @PiyushKhanna, please see the updated question above, I have included the stored procedure as well. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not effective create stored procedures for CRUD operations. If you have a lot of tables, create c# support in your application for generating SQL commands (Insert, Update, Delete) and send them in transaction (TransactionScope) - as SqlCommand with parameters - into database.

Comment: Hi @bmi, so what about if I have more than 1 need to be inserted into the database? should I do the for loop instead and execute CRUD operation 1 by 1 per time, instead of sending a bunch of data into database, and let the database for loop it? Thanks

Comment: There is not reason to send sql commands in for loop (except large amount of sql commands - this can be solved by bulk sql command). But in complicated systems may be executed separated sql command executions - this doesnt matter - but it slightly raise sql traffic. All you can execute as one sql command (all inserts, updates, deletes) execute at once.